# Using Thrift and Apache.Cassandra in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'd like to connect to Cassandra (already running on localhost) from C# (with Visual Studio IDE) using the "Thrift" and the "Apache.Cassandra" resources.

The first question is... shall I use a client like "cassandra-sharp" or the resources previously mentioned? I found an example (http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2009/11/06/net-developers-guide-to-getting-started-with-cassandra.aspx) using those resources and it seems easy to me.

And the second (stupid) question is: how can I external resources in Visual Studio? I installed NuGet and I downloaded Thrift (still looking for "Apache.Cassandra"), now it's placed in the "References" directory and I wrote "using Thrift.Protocol", etc in declarations... 
but when I try to debug I get some errors like:

"The type or namespace name 'TTransport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Thank you all for the help,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1):

Get one of available clients for C# first, then learn if you need to build your own.

If you decide you'd like to build your own client (including connection pooling), you need to download from http://thrift.apache.org/download/ Thrift C# library sources (currently v.0.8) to include into your project, an msbuild task or Thrift.exe compiler to build C# Cassandra proxy sources/library from cassandra.thrift.